# What can Protectorate do to counter Epic Haley's Feat?

Tags: warmachine, miniatures

So, I have a friend who plays Cygnar in Warmachine.  I play Protectorate, and he has been playing a LOT of Epic Haley.  Her feat basically makes you 1) Forfeit either an action or a movement and 2) He chooses the order your units activate in.

This causes me some problems, as the style of Protectorate I play is all about synergies and moving correctly.  I have been struggling against her for months now, and am trying to find some kind of strategy against her, whether that be play-style, units/casters, etc.

Comment: Really old question, but Haley2 has been tweaked in the last 8+ years. Haley's player no longer controls your turn: `Choose d3+5 enemy models currently in Haley's control range. The chosen models must forfeit either their Normal Movement or Combat Action during their next activations. Temporal Shift lasts for one round.` This would still be a good question how to set up to minimize it's impact, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is incredibly obvious when this feat will be used. In competitive games it will most likely be turn 2 if the Cygnar player went first, or MAYBE turn 1 if you went first, so plan for it and know that your second turn will be spent largly doing nothing. Play that turn defensively, cast defensive spells and back up, or duck into terrain. Depending on your caster, you might be able to hide a significant portion of your force only to have it bust out of the trees the next round and deal maximum damage. Just don't let the Haley player bog you down. Insist that he pick which models activate in what order in a very timely fashion so that you can end your turn and be on to the next quickly.
If you make the Cygnar army unable to see your army he can't really capitalize on knowing that your next turn is going to be rubbish.

Comment: So, I have attempted to do all of that, but have been stymied by the whole "rush out of the trees" - would this be a good place for a caster like Vindictus with his speed and pathfinder boost?  Or is there a better caster I am not thinking of?